# Alter numeric values format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a numeric column in MS SQL Server table(say column1)

The data appears like this

```
Column1
23.50000
170.50000
53.50000
```

Note : There is always 5 digits after decimal point.

Now i need a MS SQL query to display the numeric value in the following way

```
Column1
00023500
00170500
00053500
```

The transformation is 5 digits for integer part and 3 digits for decimal part.

Comment: SQL servers are not really where the data gets displayed.  What front end reporting system / website are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this on the client side

```
    RIGHT('00000000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(INT,field*1000)),8)
```

Comment: The above query is functioning in most of the examples. but if my input is 413142.5022 , the output i need to get is 41314502. but the above query returns 13142502

Comment: I don't understand what is the logic that converts 413142.5022 -> 41314502?  Are you dropping the 1s digit?  Please explain

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you need

```
    declare @t table(a dec(18,5))
    insert into @t values(23.50000),(170.50000),(53.50000),(322.50000),(413142.5022)

    select a, left(replace(replicate('0', 
    case when 6-CHARINDEX('.',cast(a as varchar),1)<0 then 0 else 
6-CHARINDEX('.',cast(a as varchar),1) end) 
    +cast(a as varchar),'.',''),8) from @t
```